# Existence and uniqueness for the spherically symmetric Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Let $V\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^p)$ ($p\geq 1$) be compactly supported, non-negative and spherically symmetric.

> > Does there exist a unique weak solution for
> >     $$ \begin{cases}
> > \left[-\Delta + V \right]f =0, \\
> > \lim_{\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0
> > \end{cases} $$ 
> >     and what can be said about the regularity of $f$?

Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Section §3.4](https://books.google.it/books?id=fajzCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=berezin%20shubin&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q=181&f=false) of Berezin-Shubin's "The Schrödinger equation" might help, I hope.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: Could you find the answer?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Unfortunately not yet. Tomorrow morning I'll continue to search.

Comment: With $V=0$ you have no nontrivial solutions. Indeed, weak solutions are automatically smooth by elliptic regularity, and so they are harmonic functions. The only harmonic function that vanishes at infinity is $0$. This is not much, I agree, but HTH

Comment: I suspect that the answer is affirmative. First, all solutions must be radially symmetric (to be proven, we can discuss this if you want). Second, a radially symmetric solution solves a second-order Ode with two boundary conditions : one at infinity and one at $0$, forced by the fact that the solution must be smooth there. Therefore the solution *should* be unique. This is 100% hand-wavy, though.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I thought about the solutions being radially symmetric, but I had no clue how I could prove such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS A COMMENT**

This is how I thought of proving that solutions are radially symmetric. There are a couple points where I am not entirely sure, though.

Anyway, the idea is to write $x=r\omega$, with $r=|x|$ and $\omega \in \mathbb S^{p-1}$, and decompose $f$ in spherical harmonics: 
$$f=\sum_\ell c_\ell(r) Y_\ell(\omega). $$ 
The task is to prove that $c_\ell=0$ unless $\ell=0$. The Laplacian is decomposed in a radial and in an angular part: 
$$-\Delta = -\Delta_r -\frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{\omega}, $$ 
and since $V$ is radial, the equation $[-\Delta + V]f=0$ is equivalent to the infinite system of ODEs 
$$\tag{1}
(-\Delta_r +V +\frac{\ell(\ell+d-2)}{r^2})c_\ell(r)=0,\quad \ell=0, 1, 2,\ldots$$ 
(The number $\ell(\ell+d-2)$ comes out from $-\Delta_\omega Y_\ell = \ell(\ell+d-2)Y_\ell$, but this is not important. What is important is that this number is nonnegative and that it vanishes if and only if $\ell=0$).

*Since the solution must be smooth at $0$* (actually I am not so sure this is true since $V$ is not smooth itself), we have the two boundary conditions 
$$
c'_\ell(0)=0,\quad \lim_{r\to \infty} c_\ell(r)=0, $$ 
which are incompatible with (1) unless $c_\ell=0$ by some form of the maximum principle (and here I am also not entirely sure).